# How can I install yum?

Tags: php, yum, smart

I've downloaded a fedora-based embedded linux (Endian Firewall Community release 2.5.1). The version of kernel is 2.6.32.43-57.e43.i586. It only has smart package management (and rpm). I can't install yum package manager, and also there is no gcc/gmake to install yum from source. I want to install PHP through yum and I can't install php through rpm. There is error and also so many errors. Do you know where is the channel smart checks to install dependencies? I got fedora 18 and the RPM packages don't install and show cpio error of public key.. How can I install yum?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Endian Firewall does not come with Yum, thus there are no specific repos.

http://iandunn.name/installing-additional-software-on-endian-firewall/

Comment: when I type smart install  http://vault.centos.org/4.0/os/i386/CentOS/RPMS/yum-2.2.0-1.centos4.2.noarch.rpm, I get the error below:
public key not available
the same error with smart install 
http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/os/i386/CentOS/yum-3.2.22-40.el5.centos.noarch.rpm

Thanks!

Comment: that error has gone by set conf FALSE description I didn't see before. Anyways; the new error: Can't install yum-2.2.0-1.centos4.2@noarch: no package provides yumconf

Comment: Can you include the main points of the article here. If the link ever dies your answer won't be much use.

Comment: I added channel to smart and php is being installed. hope it will work.